# How to use selected option in vue dropdown bar as a parameter in a link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameters, vuetify.js

I have this autocomplete feature in vue where I am populating an autocomplete dropdown with values from a json-server. Below is the relevant code blocks:

```
  <v-autocomplete dense
        filled
        label="Subject: "
        v-model="subject"
        :items="subject"
        item-text='example'
        item-value='example'>
        <option v-for="example in subject" v-bind:key="example.id" v-bind:title="example.title">{{ example }}</option>
</v-autocomplete>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Inbox',
    data() {
        return {
            subject: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/subject')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.subject = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message)),
```

How would I be able to use the selected value from the dropdown as a parameter to access the actual value within the database? For example I want to use the selected value to make this call.

```
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/subject=THE SELECTED VALUE')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `items` prop as the list of all your subjects, and `v-model="selectedSubject"` will only contain the selected value.
plus you should not use `<option>` inside `v-autocomplete` it already does it for you.
So now you can listen to `@change` event and call `fetch` when `subject` has changed:

```html
<v-autocomplete dense
     filled
     label="Subject: "
     v-model="selectedSubject"
     :items="subjects"
     item-text='example'
     item-value='example'
     @change='fetchSubject'
>
</v-autocomplete>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    subjects: [],
    selectedSubject: null,
  }
},
mounted() {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/subject')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => this.subjects = data)
     .catch(err => console.log(err.message)),
},
methods: {
  fetchSubject(selectedSubject) {
    if (selectedSubject) {
       fetch(`http://localhost:3000/subject=${selectedSubject}`).then((res) => {
           // do your actions
       })
    }
  }
}
```